# Real Analysis vs. Functional Analysis version of Arzela-Ascoli Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider a collection of functions defined on a compact set such that they are uniformly bounded and equicontinuous. Then

1) Real analysis version: Every sequence in that collection will contain a uniformly convergent subsequence

2) Functional analysis version: The collection is relatively compact i.e. its closure is compact. i.e. any sequence in its "closure" will have a uniformly convergent subsequence in the "closure".

Which one is the correct statement ? Or, I may be missing something trivial.

Comment: Could you edit with the definite statements for both $1$ and $2$?

Comment: @Aram: "definite statement" ??

Comment: Statements of the theorems...

Comment: @Aram: Modified a bit. I think the first one is much stronger. But, I am confused about how they are equivalent. In general functional analysis version should be stronger.

Comment: in the 'real analysis version', the limit of the subsequence is not necessarily an element of the collection but of its closure.

Comment: @daw: I am not at all bothered about where the limit lies at all, the question is only where the uniformly convergent subsequence lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual statement of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem is closer to the "functional analysis version", except that there's no "pointwise convergent" (which doesn't make sense for a set) and the set is assumed to be **equicontinuous**.

EDIT: Given the "real analysis version", the "functional analysis version" can be deduced as follows.  Suppose $S$ is a set of functions on $X$ that are uniformly bounded and equicontinuous: there is $B$ such that $|f(x)| \le B$ for all $f \in S$ and $x \in X$, and for every $\epsilon > 0$ and $x \in X$ there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ for all $y \in U$ and all $f \in S$. Let $\overline{S}$ be the uniform closure of $S$.  Then I claim $\overline{S}$ is also uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, so applying the "real analysis version" to it we can conclude that any sequence in $\overline{S}$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence.

In fact, take any $\widetilde{B} > B$.  For any $g \in \overline{S}$, there is 
$f \in S$ with $|g - f| < \widetilde{B} - B$ everywhere, and then 
$|g(x)| \le |g(x) - f(x)| + |f(x)| \le B$.  Similarly, given $x\in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$, take $0 < \eta < \epsilon$ and neighbourhood $U$ of $x$
such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \eta$ for $y \in U$ and $f \in S$.  Given $g \in \overline{S}$, take $f$ so $|g - f| < (\epsilon - \eta)/2$, and we find that
for $y \in U$, 
$$ |g(x) - g(y)| \le |g(x) - f(x)| + |f(x) - f(y)| + |f(y) - g(y)| < \epsilon $$

Comment: A set is contained in its closure, so I do not understand your qualifier "only talks about closure".

Comment: What do you mean?  Since every member of set $S$ is contained in the closure of $S$, every property that is true for all members of the closure is true for all members of $S$.

Comment: A subsequence is a subset.  If members of the original sequence are in $A$, the members of the subsequence is also in $A$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Sorry, i wrote it wrongly. I did not want to mean that. 2) -> 1) proof is obvious. To prove 1) -> 2) suppose we take a sequence in closure, then if it contains only finite number of elements from the original set, then what to do ? How do I prove that this sequence has a convergent subsequence. My main confusion is the presence of "closure" in 2) but not in 1). Hope I have made my point clear.